# Randomize what string to print in c

Tags: c, random

I got a quick question. Is it possible to 'randomize' the output I get? For example in the first run I get 'Magic number 1', and when I run it again, I could get 'Magic number 3'. I couldn't find any help elsewhere.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
char *a = "Magic number 1\n";
char *b = "Magic number 2\n";
char *c = "Magic number 3\n";

printf("%s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to edit the code to

```
printf("%s", a||b);
```

But || is used only to logic, right?

Comment: Easiest way would be put the stings in array then pick a random array index. Alternative is a big `if` statement (or `switch` statement) to print individual variables.

Comment: You'll probably want to use `srand()` and `rand()` from `<stdlib.h>` to generate random numbers.  You'll probably want an array of string pointers rather than three separately named variables.  Using `printf("%s", a || b)` passes an `int` (either `0` or `1`) to a format expecting a character string.  Since `a` is a non-null pointer, the `a || b` expression always evaluates to `1`.  Happiness does not ensue.

Comment: With the three strings shown, you could use `printf("Magic number %d\n", rand() % 3 + 1)` to print an appropriate string.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Also, is it possible to 'delete' or disable a variable? For example if I run the code, and it prints out the a, can it be done that in the next runs it can't print a no more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` produces an *`int`* either 1 or 0 based on the truth of the logical OR statement.

What is happening in the statement `printf("%s", a||b);` is that the value `1` (since the addresses of the string pointers being compared are non-zero, thus the OR is true and returns `1`) is attempted to be accessed as the pointer to a null-terminated string. This is undefined behavior, and very likely going to crash (if you're lucky).

If you want to print a random string from a set of variables in your code, what you can do is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

 // (in main())
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));  
    int r = rand()%3;
    if(r == 0)
        puts(a);
    else if(r == 1)
        puts(b);
    else
        puts(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?
Instead of creating seperate variables for each of them, you can use 2D arrays.

```
  int main() {
      char arr[3][100] = {"Magic number 1\n", "Magic number 2\n", "Magic number 3\n"};
      int i, range=3;
      srand((unsigned)time(NULL));  
      i = rand()%range;
      puts(arr[i]);
      return 0;
    }
```